# django locale can't translate depend on accept-language

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, translate, http-accept-language

Here is my settings

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('zh_CN', u'简体中文'),
    ('en-us', u'English'),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # "django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware",

)
```

Here is some print

```
('django_language', '')
('COOKIES', '')
('ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 'zh_CN')
('LANGUAGE_CODE', 'en-us')
```

My django version is `1.5.4`

If i set

```
request.session['django_language'] = 'zh_CN'
```

I will get translation next time. What's wrong ?

Comment: What is FULL URL? Did you pass language prefix in URL?

Comment: @Kaushal no.FULL URL is {{HOST}}/api/calendarevent/eventtype/.  but according to the document.
i can use accecpt-language without set language prefix? right?

Comment: Right You can use without url prefix. But I thought may be url prefix conflict with accept header. Did you used `django rest`? which version of `django-rest` ? if `< 3.00`did you check if  `2.XX` support Internationalization

Comment: @Kaushal I use rest 2.4.5

Comment: internationalization support added in rest framework from `rest framework 3.1`  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/ So  I think you can not use directly

Comment: also `zh-cn` is correct config name not `zh_CN'  for django version before 1.7.